# how to submit a text input to somewhere that i can collect submissions

Tags: javascript, html

I'm really stuck on this I'm not sure how I would code text being sent or where i could send it to

```
           <div class="comment-box">
           <h2> submit quiz </h2>
           <form action="#">
           <input type="text" name="full_name" placeholder="Full Name...">
           <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address...">
           <button type="submit">submit comment</button>
           </form>
```

any help or ideas on how i can do this would be great

Comment: depends on what you want to do with the information.

Comment: Please clarify what exactly the problem(s) you're facing and what you tried and isn't working. Also, add a [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: do you wanna send it via email?

Comment: do you need to send the request to a server-side script?

Comment: if you want to send it to a mail box add the email in the form action`<form action="mailto:someone@example.com">`.but note this will not automatically send the email.it will open the default mail app and put the info in the email body.users will still have to press the send button

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to receive this information via email and need a quick and easy solution (however not reccomended), you can use this form tag

```html
<form action=”mailto:contact@yourdomain.com” method=”POST” enctype=”text/plain” name=”EmailForm”>
```

Ensure you change the email in the `form action=""` tag.

You can also look into using a more advanced method through PHP.